This bird is so popular, many countries around the world share a name with it
There's a bird, it's very popular.
Several IRL Earth countries (more than 2) around the world share a name with the same bird, although the relation between the country name and the bird is not obvious. For each of these countries, you must think in a foreign language.
Named After, meaning:

To give (someone or something) the name of another person, place, or thing; to name (someone or something) in honour of synonym


What's this bird's scientific name?
What countries were named after it?
In what foreign language were they related, in each case?

Hints:

Those are nations recognized by the UN. Real countries.


 2. At least two of these foreign languages are among the 10 most spoken in the world.


 3. The bird isn't known for its flying skills.


 4. Most natives of these nations don't know their country share a name with the bird, unless they know the matching foreign language.


 5. No two countries in the answer share the same tectonic plate.


 6. When people do eat the bird, it's often in the second half of the year.

EDIT: The countries weren't named after the bird, i.e. "baptized" after the bird's name. It's a coincidence.

Is "named after" correct here or just "named the same as"?

@hexomino from my deleted answer, it's an important distinction.

@WeatherVane I don't mind you keeping the answer, perhaps with some clarification. After a while of searching I was unable to find a suitable answer - the best I could find was two countries named after the same bird but the etymology of one of them is disputed.

@hexomino added a formal definition.

By "country" do you mean "sovereign state" or "expanse of land"?

I can find 2 candidate countries but with a different bird.  Columbia (columba) and ancient Gaul (gallus).  If it can help.

@Florian F Columbia was named after Christopher Columbus I thought.

True, but I assume Columbus somehow got his name from the bird (a dove).  So it is indirectly named after the bird.  It is the best I found anyway.

Wikipedia has a list of country name etymologies. It lists two with possible blackbird etymologies.

@msh210 saw them, Kosovo and Chile but they aren’t under one language. Also Kenya apparently means the mountain of ostriches. I can’t find anything else too promising

@caPNCApn yes, real world nations. Added it as a hint.

@MindwinRememberMonica I am little confused here, can you explain the third question a little more clearly? Do you mean ‘with what foreign language are they related?’

@pdt i'll add a fourth hint.

@PDT It doesn't sound like "being under one language" is a requirement (i.e. it's okay for the countries to be named for the same bird but in different languages). I'd say make that an answer.

@F1Krazy Not a single language otherwise either one language has several names for the same bird (possible but unlikely) or all the countries have the same name (impossible). I made a little change on the first paragraph: "For each of these countries, you must think in a foreign language." which also works together with hint #4

@Fluorine I say post it as an answer and find out!

I don't get why "real world nations" (IRL) is even mentioned. We assume the real world unless otherwise stated.

@Fluorine I would not say so, instead the bird was named after the country.

@Fluorine WeatherVane posted an answer along these lines earlier and although the other possible countries share the name of the bird in other languages, they are not named after the bird as defined in the question.

@Fluorine yes, that's right, it's what initially prompted my first question.

@hexomino thanks for pointing it out. Language barrier, I'm going to fix the first paragraph. The countries weren't intentionally named after the bird, it was a coincidence.

You should also remove the definition, it is also misleading. Now we just wait for @WeatherVane to undelete their answer i guess

I don't think my answer was good enough, and it was a very poorly phrased question (even after prompting), along with the strange insistence that it should be a real country, in real life.

It's a little frustrating because I convinced WeatherVane and Fluorine that their answers were wrong because you posted the definition of "named after". I understand that there may be a language barrier but you could have checked the translation of your definition.

I think that you are referring to

 Meleagris gallopavo

Which in

 English is referred to as the turkey.

but in

 French is called the dinde (meaning from India)

and in

 Russian is the indyushka (little Indian bird)

and in

 Polish and Ukrainian indyk

and in

 Turkish Hindi

and in

 Portuguese Peru.


why the downvotes? Daniel got all 3 countries correctly.

@MindwinRememberMonica I'm only counting 2 countries, in the second and in the last spoiler block?

second, third, and last blocks. 3 countries.
